# How can we get a randomly selected element from an array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, random

How can i find or get a randomly selected element from an array in Scala ???

The code for getting a random value is simple that is :

```
var rand :Int= scala.util.Random
println(rand.nextInt)
```

Comment: Create a random int between `0` and `array.length` then access the array with than random index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

```
import scala.util.Random

val anArray = ...

val randomElement = anArray(Random.nextInt(anArray.length))
val anotherElement = Random.shuffle(anArray).head
```

Take your pick, but be forewarned that neither of these is safe if `anArray` is empty.

Comment: `.headOption` ?

Answer (score 1):

use `Random.nextInt`. Probably `Random.shuffle` will cost much more.

```scala
import scala.util.Random

def randElem[T](arr:Array[T]):Option[T] = arr.length match {
  case 0 => None
  case s => Some(arr(Random.nextInt(s)))
}

println(randElem(Array("F", "U", "N"))) //Some(N)
println(randElem(Array())) //None
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/0Vl2Ssh/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random
val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
val myArray = Array(1,2,3,4)
val randomIndex = rand.nextInt(myArray.length)
val result = myArray(randomIndex)
println(result)
```